# Report Uptime Metrics for SQL Server by Database/Application

Tags: sql-server, metrics

I have a requirement to report monthly metrics on SQL Server uptime, by application/database. This would be at the cluster level. I.E., if a secondary replica went offline, but a primary was still available to process transactions, uptime would still be considered 100%.

I've looked at various tools that might serve this purpose, and a few come close. But, none of them seem to capture anything more than if the SQL Server service is online and accepting connections. They also fail to aggregate these metrics at the cluster/AG level. Meaning these uptime reports would take a hit if a secondary replica were to go offline.

For example, let's say a database goes offline or a log file fills up, and transactions are unable to process against a single database. Those tools would say that SQL Server is up, but I would still have people saying it was a database issue. Thus, these metrics would need to reflect that SQL was not fully up at that time.

The best idea of I'm come up with at this point is to create a SQL Agent job that inserts a record into a Canary table in each database, once a minute. Then at the end of the month, to query that table and divide the previous month's row count by the expected row count. I figured there was no better way to prove a database was actually available than to try to insert a row.

I already have the above solution developed, tested and working. But I'm curious if anyone knows of a better way to do this. Including any goods tools or DMVs I may have overlooked, that I could use to extrapolate end-user availability metrics of all databases on a SQL Instance?

Comment: "*if a secondary replica went offline, but a primary was still available to process transactions, uptime would still be considered 100%*" - since you want to measure it at an AG level, I assume the reverse scenario would still be considered 100% by your metrics?...i.e. if the primary goes offline and the AG fails over to the secondary replica, because the secondary replica was immediately promoted to the primary it's still 100% uptime?...what about the case where the AG can't auto-promote a secondary replica, e.g. when there's only 1 replica left during failover?

Comment: Correct, the only downtime, if any, would be during the failover. Which with AG, is typically near zero. If there were no available replicas to promote, and the primary went offline, that would be down time. Basically, it boils down to what the application would see as down time. If that helps.

Comment: The problem is most monitoring tools just look at uptime of all SQL Servers, and only at the service being up.

Comment: I do know there's some DMVs for Availability Group metrics, which is what the Availability Group Dashboard basically uses under the hood. Not sure if there's anything of help in there, I have to refresh myself. Will post an answer if I find anything of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I'm using, which is working.

The below stored procedure can be used to populate a Canary table, and can be  executed each minute from a SQL Agent job.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SQLUptime]
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE
        @DatabaseName nvarchar(128),
        @Query nvarchar(max);

    DECLARE cDatabases CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [name]
        FROM sys.databases
        WHERE database_id > 4

    OPEN cDatabases;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cDatabases INTO @DatabaseName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            IF COALESCE(sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica(@DatabaseName),1) = 1    
            BEGIN
                SET @Query = 'USE [' + @DatabaseName + ']' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 
                    'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = N''dba'')' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 
                    'BEGIN' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    '    EXECUTE sp_executesql N''CREATE SCHEMA [dba]''' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    'END' +  CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
            
                    'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dba].[Canary]'') AND type in (N''U''))' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    'BEGIN' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    '    CREATE TABLE dba.Canary (' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    '        [Time] Datetime NOT NULL' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    '    )' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
            
                    '    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_Canary_Time ON dba.Canary ([Time]);' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    'END' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +

                    'INSERT INTO dba.Canary ([Time])' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    'VALUES (getdate());' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
            
                    'DELETE FROM dba.Canary' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +
                    'WHERE [Time] < DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE());'

            /*PRINT @Query*/
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
        END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT
                ERROR_NUMBER(),
                ERROR_STATE(),
                ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
                ERROR_LINE(),
                ERROR_MESSAGE()
        END CATCH
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM cDatabases INTO @DatabaseName
    END

    CLOSE cDatabases;
    DEALLOCATE cDatabases;
END
```

The following query can then be used each month to report uptime based the number of rows successfully inserted into the Canary table during the previous month.

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate    datetime,
    @CutoffDate   datetime,
    @TotalMinutes int,
    @output       int,
    @SQL          nvarchar(500),
    @Parameters   nvarchar(500),
    @Database     nvarchar(128);

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-1,0);
SET @CutoffDate = DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDate));

IF @CutoffDate > GETDATE()
    SET @CutoffDate = GETDATE();

SET @TotalMinutes = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate,@CutoffDate);
SET @Parameters = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UptimeMinutes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #UptimeMinutes

CREATE TABLE #UptimeMinutes (
    DatabaseName nvarchar(128),
    UptimeMinutes int
)

DECLARE cursorDatabases CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT [name]
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id > 4;

OPEN cursorDatabases;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDatabases INTO @Database;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'USE [' + @Database + '] SELECT @retvalOUT = COUNT(*) FROM dba.Canary';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Parameters, @retvalOUT=@output OUTPUT;

    INSERT INTO #UptimeMinutes (DatabaseName,UptimeMinutes)
    SELECT @Database, @output;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDatabases INTO @Database;
END

SELECT SUM(UptimeMinutes) InstanceUptimeMinutes,
    SUM(@TotalMinutes) AS TargetInstanceUptimeMinutes,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),(SUM(UptimeMinutes)/CONVERT(DECIMAL,SUM(@TotalMinutes))) * 100) AS InstanceUptimePercentage
FROM #UptimeMinutes;

SELECT DatabaseName,
    DatabaseUptimeMinutes,
    @TotalMinutes AS TargetDatabaseUptimeMinutes,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),(UptimeMinutes/CONVERT(DECIMAL,@TotalMinutes)) * 100) AS DatabaseUptimePercentage
FROM #UptimeMinutes;

CLOSE cursorDatabases;
DEALLOCATE cursorDatabases;
```